# How could i remove the text in bold using formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need only the author names, the text in bold i want to remove that. how could i do this using excel

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below

```
=LEFT(B2,SEARCH("(",B2)-1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use LEFT():

```
=TRIM(LEFT(B2,FIND("(",B2)-1))
```